# Add code examples on your page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code inside string

```
string_eng += '<b>Year Bonus</b> - bonus for each year</br></br>';
```

And I want to put this inside textarea, but when I do it, the result is:
 - bonus for each year

It simply deletes all things inside the html tags. I just want to show all the code inside the string. I already tried `<xmp>`,`<pre>`, but none of them worked.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT.
Code with which I input data from the array to the textarea/code.

```
$('body').append('<code class="code_text"></code>');

for(var i=0; i<tag_list.length; i++){
    var string='';
    string+='---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n';
    string+='tag:       '+tag_list[i][0]+'\n';
    string+='nazwa_pl   '+tag_list[i][1]+'\n';
    string+='nazwa_eng  '+tag_list[i][2]+'\n';
    string+='tekst_pl   '+tag_list[i][3]+'\n';
    string+='tekst_eng  '+tag_list[i][4]+'\n';
    string+='\n\n\n';

    $('.code_text').append(string);
}
```

Comment: a side note, I don't think `br` needs a separate closing tag :)

Comment: Please use `<br />` instead of `</br>`

Comment: And please provide the code you're using to place the HTML inside the textarea.

Comment: Please use `<br>` instead of `<br />` (XHTML) or `</br>` (invalid)

Comment: Tried a fiddle and it seems to work. As Vince has already commented, let us know how you are setting the value.

Comment: This should work: string_eng += '&lt;b&gt;Year Bonus&lt;/b&gt; - bonus for each year&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;';

Comment: @Quentin As far as I know, `<br />` is totally valid HTML 5.

Comment: @ComFreek — Valid, but pointless. It's a sop for people addicted to XHTML or who can't configure their editors to do HTML syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using jsfiddle:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var string_eng = '';
    string_eng += '<b>Year Bonus</b> - bonus for each year</br></br>';
    $("#code").html(string_eng);
});
```

**Output (*contained in textarea*)**

```
<b>Year Bonus</b> - bonus for each year</br></br>
```

**Try it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/UH53y/

It does not omit values held within tags, however if you were expecting the `<b></b>` tags to render as bold within the textarea, or the `<br />` tags to render as line breaks, this wont happen either. textarea does not support formatting.

See this question for more information: [HTML : How to retain formatting in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806673/html-how-to-retain-formatting-in-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the jQuery .append method which seems to parse the string and insert it afterwards. I don't know jQuery at all, so there might be another special jQuery method, but here is a simple fix:

```
$('.code_text').append(document.createTextNode(string));
```

**Edit:**
I just read and tried the answer of Salman A. The "special jQuery method" exists and he used it. You can use this:

```
$('.code_text').text(string);
```